# html attribute for additional information and forward usage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The question is must be quite trivial, but i don't know how to formulate it right.
Ok, I'm using PHP and jQuery, also i use ajax for user-to-server requests.
What I'm looking for is a simple way to get info about some ohhhh I'll better show an example of what i want.

I form the page with some info from DB.
For example I have a table with objects that have colors, and when page is load we have this:

```
 <body>
 <span class="object_span">red</span><button>random color</button> 
 <span class="object_span">white</span><button>random color</button>
 </body>
```

I simplified this, but you got what's the point, think.

next step, I want to change one of this using ajax:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
 $('#object_span').change(function(){

  $.post(
'ajax_handler.php',  
    {object_id: 'how to simply get this parameter???' },  //         <---- problem is here
    function(responseText){  
    console.log(responseText);  
    },  
    "html"  
  );  

  });
 });
```

may be there is some parameter that i can add to span like: 'my_object_id:1232' ?? or something in this way that i can simply use in the js or jQuery like so:

```
     $(document).ready(function(){
     $('#object_span').change(function(){
     var current_object_id = $('#object_span').attr('my_object_id');
     ...
     });
 });
```

Thanks, for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `data` attribute:

```
<body>
     <span class="object_span" data-my_object_id="1234">red</span><button>random color</button> 
     <span class="object_span" data-my_object_id="1235">white</span><button>random color</button>
</body>
```

Then you can do:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.object_span').change(function(){
     var current_object_id = $(this).data('my_object_id');
     ...
});
```

Comment: @RodrigoDias I agree, I merely left it as it is to help the OP understand, whilst changing as little of his code as possible :).

Comment: @RodrigoDias Actually, after trying it, I think I prefer `data-my_object_id`, putting in dashes for it all looks a little messy IMO :). Each to their own though :)

Answer (score 2):

You can assign attributs to span and access them as you access defined attributs.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/7sx7E/)**

Html

```
<span class="object_span" my_object_id="I am added">red</span>
```

Javascript

```
 $('#object_span').change(function(){
       var current_object_id = $(this).attr('my_object_id');
 });
```

You can use data-attributes name as well.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/dqKL8/)**

Html

```
<span class="object_span" data-my_object_id="I am added">red</span>
```

Javascript

```
   $('#object_span').change(function(){
        var current_object_id = $(this).data('my_object_id');           
   });
```

Comment: For cleanliness, I'd prefix it with `data`. Eg `data-object-id`.

Comment: thanks, to all that's what i'm talking about :) That's what i need:)

Comment: BTW, although it will work, the first option you stated will fail W3C validation, as it's invalid markup :)

Comment: Also, why not just use a normal `id` on the spans?

Comment: @mattytommo so, you want to say that is much better to use this construction with data: $('.object_span').data('my_object_id'); right?

Comment: @jfrej  I think if use this instead of $('.object_span') it will output right data

Comment: @mattytommo  mm could you help with jfrej question? I try to use $(this).data('my_object_id'); but it returns only the first span data('my_object_id') not the second or another. Oh jfrej delete his comment, but I hope you got what is about I ask you. Thanks once more:)

Comment: @mattytommo oh i think i got it :)))

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you take a look at HTML5 data attirbutes and jQuery data() methods